# Can the Delayed Spell metamagic feat be used with Fireball?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, feats, targeting, metamagic

Can the [Delayed Spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/delayed-spell-metamagic/) metamagic feat be used with [Fireball](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/fireball)?

Delayed Spell says:

> ...Only spells that target one or more squares or grid intersections
>   can be affected by Delayed Spell...

Fireball mentions its target as:

> You point your finger and determine the range (distance and height) at
>   which the fireball is to burst. A glowing, pea-sized bead streaks from
>   the pointing digit and, unless it impacts upon a material body or
>   solid barrier prior to attaining the prescribed range, blossoms into
>   the fireball at that point.

Would that count as targeting one or more squares or grid intersections?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## This GM would rule that [*fireball*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/fireball) can be modified by [Delayed Spell](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/delayed-spell-metamagic/)

The spell [*fireball*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/fireball) has the entry ***Area*** 20-ft.-radius spread. [Aiming a Spell](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Magic/#TOC-Aiming-a-Spell) on Area, in part, says, "Regardless of the shape of the area, you select the point where the spell originates…. The point of origin of a spell is always a grid intersection." Area spells like the *fireball* spell *essentially* target grid intersections, so this GM would allow such spells to be affected by the metamagic feat [Delayed Spell](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/delayed-spell-metamagic/).

(Given the mechanical meaning the game ascribes to the word *target*, that's poor word choice on the part of the feat Delayed Spell. If the GM is requiring that a spell specifically have in its *Target* entry the words *grid intersection* or similar language, the player may want to point out politely that [no spell in the game has the term *grid intersection* in it at all](https://cse.google.com/cse?cx=006680642033474972217%3A6zo0hx_wle8&q=grid%20intersection#gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=grid%20intersection&gsc.ref=more%3Aspells&gsc.sort=), limiting significantly the utility of the feat Delayed Spell.)

Comment: (+1 for parenthetical)